# Timeout for addRemoteCandidate. Consider sending an end-of-candidates notification

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc, ortc

In order to communicate with Browser Edge we need to set `a=end-of-candidates` as you can see [here](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/release/adapter.js#L662) . Edge to Edge and Edge to other browser its working fine. Even I am able to communicate React Native app with Chrome but for edge I need to specify this value inside my app sdp before sending to the Edge browser. Please let me know how can I achieve this sdp?

You can see [this PR of AdpaterJS](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/pull/494) as edge giving this error upon receiving the sdp from react native android app `Timeout for addRemoteCandidate. Consider sending an end-of-candidates notification`. Let me know if you required more information.

- **React Native version**: 0.56.0
- **Plugin version**: 1.63,0
- **OS**: Android
- **OS version**:Nugat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge requires a call addIceCandidate(null) when all remote candidates have been added. If you don't do that this will happen automagically after 3-4 seconds, but that increases the chance of failure.

Comment: On each received candidate i add that to `PeerConnectuon.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate), () => console.log("Success"), () => console.log("Failure"));
}`  so you suggesting i should add like this PeerConnection.addIceCandiadte(null) when other peer candiates gathering complete?

Comment: With using the adapter.js I had to put a setTimeout for 1 second around adding the  null ice candidate and then everything connected faster and with no errors or warnings!

Comment: Sorry can you put an example how your fix it  and where ? I have the same problem

Comment: @AlfredoIzquierdo. Hello. have you found a solution to the problem? I have the same problem

Comment: Same problem here too.

Comment: Same problem here, someone has a solution?