# WebRTC + Adapter.js giving addremoteCandidate error while connecting audio call in MS Edge

Tags: webrtc, microsoft-edge, ortc, sipml5

I am trying to connect audio call through [sipML5 API](https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/docgen/index.html) in MS edge using webrtc and adapter.js, but it gives error **Timeout for addremoteCandidate. Consider sending an end-of-candidates notification.**

I already tried sending addIceCandidate(null) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495599/timeout-for-addremotecandidate-consider-sending-an-end-of-candidates-notificati)  but it is not working or may be i am sending it wrong. I googled but there is not enough documentation on this.

My question is where and how can i send **addIceCandidate(null)** so adapter.js will consider it ?

My RTCPeerConnection code

```
this.o_pc = new window.RTCPeerConn(a && !a.length ? null : {
            iceServers: a, 
            rtcpMuxPolicy: "negotiate",
            iceTransportPolicy: "all",
            bundlePolicy: "balanced",
            iceCandidatePoolSize: 0
            //gatherPolicy: "all",

        }, this.o_media_constraints);
        this.o_pc.onicecandidate = tmedia_session_jsep01.mozThis ? tmedia_session_jsep01.onIceCandidate : function(e) {
            tmedia_session_jsep01.onIceCandidate(e, c);
        };
        this.o_pc.onnegotiationneeded = tmedia_session_jsep01.mozThis ? tmedia_session_jsep01.onNegotiationNeeded : function(e) {
            tmedia_session_jsep01.onNegotiationNeeded(e, c);
        };
        this.o_pc.onsignalingstatechange = tmedia_session_jsep01.mozThis ? tmedia_session_jsep01.onSignalingstateChange : function(e) {
            tmedia_session_jsep01.onSignalingstateChange(e, c);
        };
```

```
this.o_media_constraints = {
        audio: true
    };
    if (tsk_utils_get_navigator_friendly_name() == "firefox") {
        tmedia_session_jsep01.mozThis = this;
        this.o_media_constraints.mandatory.MozDontOfferDataChannel = true;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could refer to [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/issues/852) about adding end-of-candidate. And in the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addIceCandidate#Syntax), it says *If no candidate object is specified, or its value is null, an end-of-candidates signal is sent to the remote peer using the end-of-candidates a-line, formatted simply like this: `a=end-of-candidates`*.

Comment: Hi, i am unable to hear audio on safari [working demo](https://calling.hexzap.com/new/callme.html), do you think it is related to this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

This warning indicates that you never call addIceCandidate(null).
When the *other end* finishes with candidate gathering, i.e. pc.onicecandidate(event) is called event.candidate not set. Then you need to send a signaling message like e.g. {type: 'end-of-candidates'} which will cause addIceCandidate(null) to be called in Edge.

If you do not do that, adapter.js (or rather the Edge/ORTC shim) will do this for you after some time but this is far from optimal.

Comment: Thanks for answer [here is the working demo](https://calling.hexzap.com/new/callme.html). If you open it on MS edge the call is connecting but there is no audio, it it something related with addIceCandidate(null) ? This is working on all browsers (not this version) except MS edge.