# WebRTC on Edge gives "Timeout for addRemoteCandidate. Consider sending an end-of-candidates notification"

Tags: webrtc, microsoft-edge, ortc

**NOTE: Check most recent EDIT please**

I get this warning on edge:

```
Timeout for addRemoteCandidate. Consider sending an end-of-candidates notification
```

I do not understand how to fix this. I use an adapter.js and I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495599/timeout-for-addremotecandidate-consider-sending-an-end-of-candidates-notificati) where people talk about the issue. But the fix does not work.

I tried to add `pc.addIceCandidate(null)`, but it does nothing.

---

On chrome it works, ICE state goes from `checking` to `connected` really fast.

On edge the ICE state hangs on `checking` and after a few seconds goes to `new`, but it should not be new.

EDIT:

Adding `pc.addIceCandidate(null);` gives me `0: InvalidStateError`. The state before I call `pc.addIceCandidate(null);` is `new`.

I also tried using `pc.addIceCandidate({candidate:''});`, but it does nothing.

Here are the relevant parts of code, where I try to add the fix:

```
function handleIceCandidate(event) {
  console.log('icecandidate event: ', event);
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendMessage([{
      type: 'candidate',
      label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
      id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
      candidate: event.candidate.candidate
    }, room]);
  } else {
    console.log("state in End of candidates: " + pc.iceConnectionState);
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1 && pc.iceConnectionState == "new") {
      //pc.addIceCandidate(null);
      pc.addIceCandidate({candidate:''});
    }
  }
}
```

And in the socket call:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {


  if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {

    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
      sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
      candidate: message.candidate
    });
    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    console.log("state in socket: " + pc.iceConnectionState);
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1 && pc.iceConnectionState == "new") {
      //pc.addIceCandidate(null);
      pc.addIceCandidate({candidate:''});
    }
  } 
});
```

EDIT:

It looks like there is an issue in `adapter.js`:

```
if (!pc._remoteDescription) {
        return reject(makeError('InvalidStateError',
            'Can not add ICE candidate without a remote description'));
      } else if (!candidate || candidate.candidate === '') { 
        for (var j = 0; j < pc.transceivers.length; j++) {
          if (pc.transceivers[j].rejected) {
            continue;
          }
          pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate({});
          sections = SDPUtils.getMediaSections(pc._remoteDescription.sdp);
          sections[j] += 'a=end-of-candidates\r\n';
          console.log("tries to send end of candidates (I added this)");
          pc._remoteDescription.sdp =
              SDPUtils.getDescription(pc._remoteDescription.sdp) +
              sections.join('');
          if (pc.usingBundle) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

It should go into the `else if`, but it never does it. I tried to `console.log(candidate.candidate)` and it shows me `undefined`. I tried adding
`|| candidate.candidate == undefined` to the else if conditions, but still it wont go into the `else if`.

Actually it feels already wrong to modify the adapter.js file. I also verified that I use an up to date version, I have no clue whats going on here and why it seems I am the only one with this problem on edge.

EDIT:

The best approach I have atm. is using `pc.addIceCandidate(null)` only here:

```
function handleIceCandidate(event) {
  console.log('icecandidate event: ', event);
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendMessage([{
      type: 'candidate',
      label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
      id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
      candidate: event.candidate.candidate
    }, room]);
  } else {
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
      pc.addIceCandidate(null);
    }
  }
}
```

This will go into the `else if` in adapter.js where it tries to append `a=end-of-candidates\r\n`, but it fails before with:

```
0: InvalidAccessError
```

Its this line in adapter.js:

```
pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate({});
```

I think I need to add the `null` candidate here, I tried different syntax variants, but no success:

```
pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate(null);
pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate({candidate:''});
pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate();
pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate({""});
```

From Microsoft [Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/mt433079%28v%3Dvs.85%29) on Edge:

> When the remote RTCIceGathereremits its final candidate,
>   addRemoteCandidate() should be called with an RTCIceCandidateComplete
>   dictionary as an argument, so that the local RTCIceTransport can know
>   there are no more remote candidates expected, and can enter the
>   "completed" state.

I tried:

```
pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate(new RTCIceCandidateComplete({complete:true}));
pc.transceivers[j].iceTransport.addRemoteCandidate({complete:true});
```

The first one gives me:

```
RTCIceCandidateComplete is not defined
```

Comment: Please check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/mt433107(v%3Dvs.85)#examples

Comment: @Roman, Hello. Have you fixed this issue? I have the same problem in Edge

Comment: @user233428 No, it seems it does not work on the old Edge versions. But I noticed that windows recently updates Edge to the chromium based Edge. Hopefully the issue will vanish then.